# Store the value of button click in variable, so that it can be stored in Sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, buttonclick, sharepoint-list

I tried to store the value of button click in variable and then using that varibale to store in sharepoint list,but the data is not getting stored in sharepoint list. Below is the HTML Button part, I just want to store the value of button click in a variable, so that I can store the value Sharepoint list.

```
<button type="button" id="btn-submit-feedback4" value="Article4"  class="btn_article">Download</button></a>
<button type="button" id="btn-submit-feedback3" value="Article5"  class="btn_article">Download</button></a>

<script>

    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var listTitle = "SeriesArticle";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { });
                var id;
            $(".btn_article").click(function () {
               insertFeedback();
              id=this.value;
              })
    });
    
    
    

    
    function insertFeedback() {
        $(".page_loading_section").show();
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteurl);
        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        
    
       
       
         var value1 = document.getElementById('txtname')  
        .value;  
    
    var value2 = document.getElementById('txtdesignation')  
        .value;  
      
        var articlename=id;
        this.oListItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

        oListItem.set_item('Title', "Aticle Series");

       
        oListItem.set_item('Bunit', bname);
        oListItem.set_item('BUnit', bunit);
        
         oListItem.set_item('ArticleTitle', articlename);
        oListItem.update();
        clientContext.load(oListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        $(".page_loading_section").hide();
       
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        writeToConsole(args.get_message());
        logMessageToULS(args.get_message());
        //  console.log(+args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        $(".page_loading_section").hide();
    }



    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should put the `var id;` outside function because it isn't accessible, and don't forget to put the `id = this.value` before `insertFeedback();` to make sure this `id` is already stored the value.

and the code will be like this:

```
var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var listTitle = "SeriesArticle";
var id;
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {});
    $(".btn_article").click(function () {
       id = this.value;
       insertFeedback();      
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code as below and tested in my SPO environment, please take a reference:

```html
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".btn_article").click(function (e) {
        // show loading scanner
        //$(".page_loading_section").show();

        // insert
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
            insertFeedback(e.currentTarget.value);
        });

    })
});

function insertFeedback(v) {
    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var listTitle = "SeriesArticle";

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteurl);
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

    var articlename = v;

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    oListItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', "Aticle Series");
    oListItem.set_item('mytitle', articlename);

    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    //$(".page_loading_section").hide();
    console.log("inserted successful");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log(+args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    //$(".page_loading_section").hide();
}
```

BR